# Using .not() with bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popovers

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
```

I need to modify this code to prevent launching popover if the element has certain data attribute.

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').not('[data-nopopover=1]').popover();
```

For some reason the popover is still triggered, even though the data attribute is present.

HTML

```
<span data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" data-content="popover content" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="" title=""></span>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you just do `.not('[data-nopopover]')`? Without "=1".

Comment: It still does it... I was wondering if it's because I add data-attribute dynamically. Maybe I need to incorporate .on() somehow.

Comment: Can you post the HTML-Code you are using?

Comment: You need to set `data-nopopover="1"` in you HTML if you don't want the element to be triggered.

Comment: It is there, but it is added later on other element click. I did verify and see it there.

Comment: `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').not('[data-nopopover="1"]').popover();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bound the popover to all elements having `data-toggle=popover` you need to destroy the popover for the elements which shouldn't show a popover. Calling `$('[data-toggle=popover]').not('[data-nopopover=1]').popover();` will just try to initialize the popover on the elements not having the `data-nopopover` attribute again. The elements having `data-nopopover` will still have the popover attached.
You should call `$('[data-nopopover=1]').popover('destroy');`

If you bind it only once to the elements, it depends on how you set `data-nopopover`. It needs to be set like this: `$('your-selector').attr('data-nopopover', "1");
$('[data-toggle=popover]').not('[data-nopopover=1]').popover();`

I created a Fiddle where you can play around: https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/72/